# i am getting passed files has no features error in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

i am getting below error message when i run cucumber. i have a particular scenario outline when i run that i am getting the below error

[TestNG] Running:
C:\Users\C076131\Desktop\Git Eclipse\ceiwires\testng.xml

`[ERROR] Unable to authenticate with Artifactory, your credentials need updating in ResourceConfig.xml`
`2022-03-23T19:32:53.788 - Test: io.cucumber.testng.CucumberExceptionWrapper@280461d3 - Starting`
`Mar 23, 2022 7:32:55 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser parseForFeature`
`INFO: File 'C:\Users\C076131\Desktop\Git Eclipse\ceiwires\target\cucumber-reports\Cucumber.json' does not contain features`
`Mar 23, 2022 7:32:55 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser parseJsonFiles`
`INFO: File 'C:\Users\C076131\Desktop\Git Eclipse\ceiwires\target\cucumber-reports\Cucumber.json' contains 0 features`
`Mar 23, 2022 7:32:55 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder generateErrorPage`
`INFO: Unexpected error`
`net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: Passed files have no features!`
`at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:79)`
`at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:93)`
`at com.usbank.applicationFramework.runner.RunnerBase.generateCucumberReport(RunnerBase.java:205)`
`at com.usbank.applicationFramework.runner.RunnerBase.afterSuite(RunnerBase.java:165)`
`at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
`at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)`
`at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)`
`at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)`
`at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)`
`at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)`
`at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)`
`at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)`
`at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:357)`
`at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)`
`at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)`
`at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)`
`at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)`
`at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)`
`at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)`
`at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)`
`at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)`
`at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)`
`at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)`

Answer (score 1):

From the error message:  `Unable to authenticate with Artifactory, your credentials need updating in ResourceConfig.xml` it looks like you need to update your credentials in ResourceConfig.xml. This sounds like something a team mate should be able to help you with if you don't know how.